# How to test the current directroy?

Tags: bash, shell

I wish to test if the current directory in which I am is "/home/$year/$month"

I have the following code:

```
cd home                       #main directory
for years in */; do           #to access all directories in "home"

    year=${years::-1}         #removes the back slash at the end of the directory name
    cd "$year"
        
       for months in */; do   #access all directories in directory "year"
           month=${months::-1}
           cd "month" || continue   #If there is a directory called "month", the 
                                    #program continues the further executions, 
                                    #else the program continues to the next folder in "year"


#witouth the above condition, the execution will run in the directory "year" which is not correct
 
           for file in *.txt; do
               rm "$file"
           done
       done
done
```

I finally ended up reaching the solution :)

Comment: In Bash, variable names are case-sensitive.  Consider trying `[[ $PWD == "/home/$year/$month" ]]`.  Also, your `cd "month"` should probably be `cd "$month"`.  Also, your `for` loop overlaps your `if-else-fi` block.  Also, you should probably quote `$file` for use, especially with `rm "$file"`.  Also, syntax is `for ...; do ...; done` and `if ...; then ...; [ else ...; ] fi`.  I'd also suggest including `if [[ ! -d ... ]]; then continue; fi` or `[[ -d ... ]] || continue` "checks".

Comment: _if the current directory in which I am is_  : The first thing your script is doing, is to move out from the current directory, which means that you loose the information what this directory was.  In fact your script seems to detect (in a unnecessarily complicated way), whether it contains a subdirectory tree of the form  `home/YEAR/MONTH`.

Answer (score -1):

I tried following code at my system:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd home
if [ 0 -eq $? ]
then
        for years in $(ls / | grep -E "[0-9]./:$")
        do
                year=${years::-1}
                cd "$year"
                if [ 0 -eq $? ]
                then
                        for months in */
                        do
                                month=${months::-1}
                                cd "$month"
                                if [ 0 -eq $? ]
                                then
                                        for file in *.txt
                                        do
                                                if [[ -f "$file" ]]
                                                then
                                                        echo "rm -i $PWD/$file"
                                                        rm -i $PWD/$file
                                                else
                                                        continue
                                                fi
                                        done
                                        cd - >/dev/null 2>&1
                                else
                                        echo "home/$year/$month directory not found"
                                fi
                        done
                        cd - >/dev/null 2>&1
                else
                        echo "home/$year directory not found"
                fi
        done
else
        echo "home directory not found"
fi
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./73145344.sh
rm -i /home/2003/Apr/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Apr/testing.txt'? n
rm -i /home/2003/Aug/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Aug/testing.txt'? n
rm -i /home/2003/Dec/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Dec/testing.txt'? n
rm -i /home/2003/Feb/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Feb/testing.txt'? n
rm -i /home/2003/Jan/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Jan/testing.txt'? n
rm -i /home/2003/Jul/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Jul/testing.txt'? n
rm -i /home/2003/Jun/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Jun/testing.txt'? n
rm -i /home/2003/Mar/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Mar/testing.txt'? n
rm -i /home/2003/May/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/May/testing.txt'? y
rm -i /home/2003/Nov/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Nov/testing.txt'? n
rm -i /home/2003/Oct/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Oct/testing.txt'? y
rm -i /home/2003/Sep/testing.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/2003/Sep/testing.txt'? n
```

Comment: There's no need for the `if [ 0 -eq $?  ]` checks.  Just do `cd home || exit` to ensure that the script aborts if the command fails.

Comment: In the inner loops, you can do `if cd ...; then ...; fi`

Comment: @William Pursell when using```cd home || exit```, the program halts and does not go to the other folders, it is a very good approach which lead me to the solution, thanks